# Can't communicate with API hosting on AWS EC2 via https

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

**Problem:**
I can send an HTTP request to my website hosted on an EC2 instance via the auto-generated IPv4 DNS (ec2-12-345-67-899.compute-1.amazonaws.com) and receive a correct response, but when I try to send an HTTPS request, the page keeps loading and I eventually got *"ec2-12-345-67-899.compute-1.amazonaws.com took too long to respond"*

**Details:**

- I am using **Flask**, **Gunicorn** as the webserver, and **Nginx** as the reverse proxy server
- Here is my **Nginx configuration file:**

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-12-345-67-899.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

- Here is what it looks like when I start my gunicorn server:
  [image: gunicorn running]
- Here is my **EC2's instance Sercurity Group:**

[image: ec2 security group]

**Notes:**
I'm a beginner so I don't know if the above information is enough. Please let me know if there's other information I need to provide.

I thought the DNS provided by the EC2 instance should be SSL-certified? If it's not then do I need to get an SSL certification and put the link to it in my Nginx Configuration file?

I tried to use Let's Encrypt but it said it cannot provide a certificate for the requested domain name (probably because the domain name belongs to Amazon).

**My ultimate goal** is to be able to communicate with my website hosted on EC2 instance via HTTPS. Is buying a domain name the only way?

Comment: Try commenting out `server_name` and restarting nginx.

Comment: I tried this and while HTTPS still doesn't load, an HTTP request returns the Nginx's default page "Welcome to Nginx! ... further configuration is required ..."